# What to do with majority opinions by scholars?

Tags: madhhab, ijma

I've read these questions and their answers on consensus (*ijma*), forming a consensus through *ijtehad*, and opinion:

- [A Question Concerning Consensus and Hadith](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12254/15498)
- [What is Ijmaa? How is it established?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/427/15498)
- [What are Ijma (izma) and qiyaas (kias) and when are they applied?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/101/15498)

I'm wondering about when there is no ijma among scholars but there are a majority of scholars who, given some hadith, think the ruling should be X and a minority who believe it should be Y, but there is still *some* agreement.

To come up with a silly example (because I've seen this several times on different topics and don't want to get answeres sidetracked by a particular topic), the scholars find a hadith that you should eat baked beans on toast on a Sunday. The majority say it means you must only eat baked beans on toast on a Sunday and *only* on Sunday but the minority think it's good but not obligatory on the Sunday bit but say you can also eat it on other days too.

What is the responsibility of the non-scholar who follows their madhhab?

- Should they go with the majority?
- Should they pick from the opinion they think is best?
- Should they avoid following either opinion? (if possible)

Perhaps there's a mechanism for this I'm unaware of, like the madhhab giving out different levels of advice?

Any insight on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ijma is not about majority but all scholars forming an opinion regarding something

Comment: This post might also be related https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35345/what-is-the-difference-between-these-terms-referring-to-a-majority-of-scholars

Comment: @Medi1Saif That was interesting and helpful, thanks.

Comment: An other relevant post https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/32558/what-is-the-difference-between-qiyas-and-istislah and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35293/what-are-basic-osol-al-fiqh-differences-similarities-between-the-4-existing?rq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know of any established rules, so this is a matter of opinion. I do not think that the opinion of the majority always translates into the opinion being correct, or the opinion that must be followed.

#### Step 1: Check the stance of the scholars

For the scholars in disagreement (the minority in this case, since your question is focused on a majority vs. a minority), check:

- Their autobiography for general level of knowledge about Islam, and their specific knowledge about the topic. If the matter is that of *fiqh* (jurisprudence), seek scholars in that domain; if it is about *hadith*, seek scholars in that domain; and so on.
- Their integrity and soundness of character. Lack of either is grounds for rejecting their fatwa (as one would also reject their testimony in court, witnessing of a wedding, etc.).

#### Step 2: Select an opinion based on your level of knowledge

If your level of knowledge about the topic is at a level that you can discern which fatwa is well supported with evidence or seems to be more correct, follow this fatwa irrespective of the number of scholars with or against it.

If you are not at that level, follow the opinion of the scholar you perceive to have more knowledge.

If you cannot tell which scholar has more knowledge, check with your *mufti*, if you have one. Then follow the opinion of your *mufti*.

If you do not have a mufti, then follow the opinion that your heart leans toward being correct as the Prophet ﷺ said in a [hadith](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:590).

#### References

You may refer to the following for more information:

- [Our attitude towards differences among the scholars](https://islamqa.info/en/22652).
- [When are the words of a scholar regarded as binding evidence?](https://islamqa.info/en/178977)
- [If he follows a scholar who is known for being knowledgeable and honest, he is not sinning](https://islamqa.info/en/105721).

Comment: Good answer and lots of info to digest, but good to see it's quite common sense. Thanks.